# How to append string to column

Tags: mysql, string, concatenation

I want to append a string as a prefix to the values of a column. When I try this one:

```
UPDATE ortsbezug SET Zusatz = CONCAT("Nordseite",Zusatz) WHERE FSOrtID = 2425;
```

I always get an error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') FROM `ortsbezug` WHERE FSOrtID = 2425 AND (Zusatz <> CONCAT("Nordseite" OR Zus' at line 1

Anyone has an idea where exactly the error could be?

[screenshot of query and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n43zl.png)

Comment: You are pasting one query and an error message that describes completely different query.

Comment: CONCAT("Nordseite" OR something) seems bad but I'd like to see the whole offending statement

Comment: I noticed that too - part of my problem! Thats definitely the error I get after using the query above

Comment: Does this happen if you use a different client? Like the mysql command line? I can't imagine that phpmyadmin or whatever you are using here is rewriting your query. If it is phpmyadmin, can you clear your browser history and all that and retry. The query erroring out here is definitely not the one you are submitting. Also (again this is unlikely given the error message) but is there a trigger for this table?

Comment: Its not CONCAT("Nordseite" OR something), I mean CONCAT ("Nordseite" + the value of column Zusatz)

Comment: I tried the MySQL workbench and it works! Clearing the cache of my browser did not help for phpmyadmin, but anyway thanks for the advice with the different client JNevill!